# angularjs ui-view html http://10.19.99.18:89/cookie/flashcookie.swf

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs 1.5.5, angular-ui-router.

```
<div class="body" ui-view></div>
```

the html in ui-view, get from server，the html change to this, detail in the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOXBW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade angularjs to 1.6.3, angularjs-ui-router to 0.4.2, angularjs-cookies to 1.6.3.

But the root cause of this problem is network hijacking.

Comment: I removed the link, as Stack Overflow is an English website. Please make sure to  [include the necessary details](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259)  of the answer here, in English, to make this a proper answer.